# What's the meaning of "soli" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar-identification

I found the following sentence in https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Victimae_paschali_laudes:

> Credendum est magis soli Mariae veraci quam ...

This appears to be literally translated into

> More trust should be placed in truthful Mary than ...

but I don't see any counterpart for `soli`, nor do I understand what `soli` means. Can you please explain this to me?

I understand the following:

- Credendum est: the following should be trusted
- magis quam B: (adverb) more than B
- Mariae veraci: dative of Marīa vērax

Comment: It might be useful to include the second part: *... quam Judaeorum turbae fallaci*; from there it is natural to see the contrast between *turbae* and *soli* (though one is adjective another is noun)

Comment: I thought this part *quam Judaeorum turbae fallaci* was irrelevant. Thank you for pointing this out!
Since your comment already states the relevance, and since there is already an answer, I guess I'll leave the question itself unamended.

Answer (score 6):

The entire verse is as follows:

> Credendum est magis soli
> Mariae veraci
> Quam Judaeorum Turbae fallaci.

The grammar is clear: "We should believe more in A than in B." *Credere* can take the dative, and that is the case of *soli Mariae veraci* and *turbae fallaci.*

The contrast is between the witness of Mary Magdalene, who in John's account was alone when she saw the resurrected Jesus (see, for instance, [John 20:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2020&version=NIV)), and what the guards of the tomb were told to say by the chief priests ([Matthew 28:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2028&version=ESV)).

The only reason I'm making this answer is that Asteroides' offered translation allows the interpretation that they "only" believe in Mary, but the point is rather that they believe in Mary, *who was alone.* A full translation:

> We should believe more in truthful Mary, who was alone, than in the deceitful crowd of the Jews.

(I should note that this verse has now been removed from the *Victimae Paschali laudes*, apparently [since 1570](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victimae_paschali_laudes), because of its "pejorative reference to the Jews.")

Comment: I interpreted Asteroides' translation exactly the same way you pointed out (*they "only" believe in Mary*), thank you!

Comment: To me the most natural sense of *soli* is not that she was alone at the time but that her testimony alone, since she is truthful, outweighs that of the *fallax turba*.

Comment: @TKR I think that reading is permissible, but it would lose the contrast between "solus" and "turba" (as d_e notes above). The juxtaposition of "sola verax" and "turba fallax" strongly recommends my reading, I think.

Comment: I don't see how it loses the contrast: the idea is that a single truthful person is more to be believed than a whole crowd of liars.

Comment: @TKR Ah, I was missing the contrast you were underlining. I was reading your "alone" as "only," i.e. "we should only believe Mary's testimony," but I think you're saying--and I agree--that "we should believe in the testimony of one person, Mary."

Comment: @brianpck: Therefore, does "soli" have two functions: Mary was "by herself" and "alone" in being truthful?

Answer (score 5):

*Soli* goes with *Mariae,* so you can translate *soli Mariae veraci* as "(in) truthful Mary alone" (as brianpck points out, "alone" in this case needs to be understood as an adjective rather than an adverb, so it would have been clearer for me to offer a translation like "Mary on her own/by herself"). *Sōlus* is one of the [adjectives with an unusual declension](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/1st-and-2nd-declension-adjectives-genitive-%C4%ABus-dative-%C4%AB) where the [genitive singular ends in *-īus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/14813/9) and the dative in *-ī* for all genders. There is a mnemonic "UNUS NAUTA".