# What is the declension for nemo?

Tags: grammar-choice, declension

I have seen different ways to decline nemo.

> Nemo neminis nemini neminem nemine (I am not including the vocative)

or

> Nemo nullius nemini neminem nullo

Which one is correct? Has it changed throughout history?

Comment: Related: [Where did the missing forms of *nemo* go?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1334/79)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Nemo* is a third declension noun, and indeed it is declined according to your first quote. However, in Classical Latin (so after [Old Latin](https://ephor.us/epitome/old-latin/), the genitive and ablative of *nullus, -ius* were used in place of *neminis* and *nemine*, as its [entry in Lewis and Short](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnemo) make clear:

> in class[ical] Lat[in] *nullius* is used for the gen[itive], and *nullo* or *nullā* for the abl[ative]

Both *neminis* and *nemine* are used in Plautus and a few times here and there afterward. Suetonius, known for his archaic language, for example, uses *nemine* frequently. But otherwise those forms basically fell out of favor.

Comment: Thank you. So, it changed through history and, for some reason, neminis and nemine stopped being used. Is there any historical reference of why this happened?

Comment: @user I don't think I've seen anyone try to explain why, just merely note that it happened. I'm not sure there's any real reason at all except that languages often change.